# How to use @react-pdf/renderer in backend nodeJs with Images and fonts

Tags: node.js, react-pdf

I have a nodeJs application, i want to create pdf in backend using  `@react-pdf/renderer`
library. My pdf contains images and external fonts. is there any way to do that?
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using @react-pdf/renderer you need to install react in nodejs. So you should have es6 support.

For that install these packages

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
```

Create a .babelrc file with this contents

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/transform-runtime"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Your script should look like

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js", # Your Path 
    "dev": "babel-node src/index.js", # Your Path 
    "build": "babel src -d dist", # If using build
  },
```

Once you are done configuring this You can use @react-pdf/renderer as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactPDF from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const pdfStream = await ReactPDF.renderToStream(<MyDocument />);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
pdfStream.pipe(res);
pdfStream.on('end', () => console.log('Done streaming, response sent.'));
```

For more details refer https://react-pdf.org/advanced#usage-with-express.js